# Is it haram to sell a product for a higher price than I bought it?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I am starting a very small business with sports goods. For example, I buy a product for RS.850 from the manufacturer and sell it to my customer for RS.1350. Is it right? If its wrong what percentage of profit should I make? I am just confused and I don't want to add haram in my business.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. I strongly recommend you to take some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. To your question: I don't think it is haram, as basically making profit is halal, but there might be a dispute on the validity of such a transaction.

Comment: Can you even have a business if you don't sell higher than you bought merchandise for?